# kafka mirrormake2 sync consumer group offset not right

Tags: apache-kafka

I use mirrormake2， the version of kafka is
in the source cluster:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh ${host} --describe --group g2 --command-config ${config}

Consumer group 'g2' has no active members.

GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
g2              t1              0          22              22              0               -               -               -
g2              t2              0          14              14              0               -               -               -
```

in the target cluster

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh ${host} --describe --group g2 --command-config ${config}

Consumer group 'g2' has no active members.

GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
g2              cluster-a.t1    0          16              22              6               -               -               -
g2              cluster-a.t2    0          1               14              13              -               -               -
```

I waited for a long time, the offset still not right